# How can I sync the most recent files from one folder to another?

Tags: rsync, file-management

I have several cameras that upload data to a Samba server running under Debian. The video files are initially uploaded to a larger external drive, but I would also like to maintain a copy of the latest files on a smaller internal drive. I have installed lsyncd and it works until it runs out of space on the smaller drive. I am looking for a solution that would automatically delete the oldest files in order to make space for the newest files.

Is there an existing piece of software that can do this, or can lsycnd be configured to handle this situation? The OS is Debian 8.5.

Comment: Ever find a good rsync solution to this? I still haven't, most fail on *only* syncing those recent ones. Sure, they all are able to delete files older than x both on source and dest, but to only ever sync the latest ones? I was able to use the --files-from option of rsync, but it fails to store full paths of the synced files correctly.  Funny how this is so hard, it should be one of the most used backup strategies, since backup traffic and storage are expensive..

Answer (score -2):

You can use **rsync** to synchronize the two directories.

A simple command could be

```
rsync -avz src/* dest
```

This will sync the contents of the *src* directory to the *dest* directory.

Comment: I am familiar with rsync, however the problem I am trying to solve is basically copying the most recent 6 GB of files from a 64 GB drive to a drive with 6 GB of free space.

Comment: This doesn't do anything remotely like what the question asks: copy the *most recent* files and *delete the oldest files*.